# Print text positioned in image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have text positioned in the center of an image, the logic is to print a certificate, and this text is generated dynamically, this occurs correctly. The problem is at the time of printing, that the text is on page 2 the image on page 1

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="DivImpressao">
    <section id="AtestadoTecnico">                          
        <img id="imgAtestado" src="~/Images/Site/AtestadoTecnico.png" runat="server" class="imgAtestadoTecnico" height="685" />                           
        <div class="txtAtestadoTecnico">
            <div style="text-align: justify; font-family: Ebrima; font-size: 10pt; margin-top: 20px">
                //texto aqui
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#AtestadoTecnico {
    width: 1014px;
    height: 670px;
    position: relative;
}

.imgAtestadoTecnico {
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}

.txtAtestadoTecnico {
    top: 100px;
    left: 120px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

JavaScript (aqui eu passo a "DivImpressao" como parâmetro para impressão:

```
function imprimePanel(elementId) {
    var printContent = document.getElementById(elementId);
    var windowUrl = 'about:blank';
    var uniqueName = new Date();
    var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime();
    var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=50000,top=50000,width=0,height=0');
    printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.focus();
    printWindow.print();
    printWindow.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from W3C [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-print/).

> Authors are cautioned that the nesting of floats, divs, and absolutely
>   positioned boxes within themselves, each other, and table cells should
>   be used carefully, since the nesting depth of these constructs is
>   printer and implementation dependent.

Which basically says that you should not use `absolute` positioning for a print because every browser and printer may (and will) do it differently (read, not the way you would expect/want).

Your best bet is either to create a simple document without using `absolute` positioning (that you may use for printing purposes), or use some third-party application to create PDF out of this document.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing your style sheet is linked with `media="screen"`. Like:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" />`

If the CSS you have should work for both print and screen you can simply remove the `media` attribute like:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />`

To define print-specific styles within the 'global' stylesheet, wrap them within

```
@media screen {
    .print-only-styles-here {...}
}
```

Or you can create a second stylesheet exclusively for print:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" media="print" />`